# SQL Server - Generate script without primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration

I'm trying to make a generated script of my data (I mean, all the INSERT INTO commands).
Because access permissions, I can't do a SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE OFF and ON (I'm using the user application in Staging)

So, there is a way to make this script in SQL Server Manager and avoid the field with the primary key?
I set to false all properties (primary, unique, etc), but the script is still sending this field (For e.g., RecID 1, 2, 3, etc).

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

**My configuration for the script:**

[image]

**Results I get:**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT -TABLE- ON 
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID,Field1) VALUES (1,'value')
```

Any solution (except for removing it with Notepad++) is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit of a work around, but sometimes useful quick and dirty way of doing these things:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO TABLE (Field1) VALUES (''' + Field1 + ''')' FROM TABLE
```

The result set will be a row for each insert statement for every row in the table TABLE. The INSERT statement is generated from concatenating the INSERT statement text with the values in Field1.

Comment: OMG, it was so easy that I never thought about it! I was thinking in make some SP with fetch cursor and etc. LOL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It comes in handy in many situations when you need to transform data and don't have regex handy... it has saved me several times over the years!

Comment: and what about nulls? I've some records with null (smalldatetime field)

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I missed this years ago, but have a look at the `COALESCE` function to map your NULLs to a string "NULL".

Answer (score 8):

There is another way to do this which is a bit more automatic and a lot less faffy when you have a lot of columns of different data types; given a table T:

```
(
  ID int identity,
  C1 nvarchar(255),
  C2 datetime
  ...
)
```

...select everything except the identity column into a new table:

```
select C1, C2, ... into InterimTable from T
```

Then:

1. Run the Generate Scripts wizard on `InterimTable`.
2. Use whatever tool you have to search the SQL for `InterimTable` and replace with `T`
3. Run